# git: List branches branched *directly* off of master

Tags: git, version-control

Essentially, I want to filter the results of `git branch --no-merged origin/master` to branches `B` such that, going backwards through `B`'s commit log, the *first* branch we encounter is `origin/master` (or, alternatively, the first branch we encounter is *not* `origin/master`).

This is maybe a kind of specific use-case but feels fairly useful. I often 'pipeline' pull requests: I'll send out a PR for review, but at the same time, begin working on a new PR branched off of the first. So if the branches look like `origin/master -> feature-a -> feature-b`, I want to know that I shouldn't send out a PR for `feature-b`, because `feature-a` should first be merged into `origin/master`.

Roughly what I want, using python:

```
import git

repo = git.Repo()
master = repo.commit('origin/master')
branch_heads = {repo.commit(b.name): b.name for b in repo.branches}

for branch in repo.branches:
  for commit in repo.iter_commits('origin/master..%s^' % branch.name):
    if commit in branch_heads:
      print branch.name, "branched from", branch_heads[commit]
      break
```

But would prefer something I could stick in ~/.gitconfig as an alias without saving and distributing that snippet.

edit:

```
git for-each-ref --shell --format='git rev-list --simplify-by-decoration origin/master...%(refname)^ --format="%d"' refs/heads/ | sh
```

This is pretty close. I think I just need to play around with some formatting options and this will be just what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem here is that branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—don't relate to each other at all.  Branch names simply identify one specific commit.  It's *commits* that relate to each other.  Branch names move over time, while commits don't: commits are permanent and unchanging, while branch names are ephemeral, like [mayflies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayfly).

That said, there *is* a formulation for what you want: given some set of commits *C<sub>1</sub>, C<sub>2</sub>, ..., C<sub>n</sub>* that are the tips of branches *B<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>2</sub>, ..., B<sub>1</sub>*, you want to start at each commit *C<sub>i</sub>* in turn, walk through its history up to but not including the commit to which `origin/master` points, and see if some other *C<sub>j, j ≠ i</sub>* points to any of those commits.  See below for what *points to* means here.

There are a couple of obvious issues to worry about here:

- It could be that *B<sub>i</sub>* and *B<sub>j</sub>* both point to the *same* commit even though *i ≠ j*:

  ```
  ...--o--o   <-- origin/master
           \
            o--o   <-- br1, br2
  ```

  The obvious thing to do here would be to throw away all but one of these branch names (choose one arbitrarily, e.g., just use `br1`) so that all *C<sub>i</sub>* are unique.
- It could be that some *C<sub>i</sub>* is not a descendant of the commit pointed-to by `origin/master`:

  ```
  ...--o--o   <-- origin/master
        \
         o   <-- br3
  ```

  The obvious thing to do here would be to throw away such branch names, so that all *C<sub>i</sub>* *are* descendants of `origin/master`.
- The branches might be rather "bushy" resulting in something like this:

  ```
  ...--o--o   <-- origin/master
           \
            \      o   <-- br4
             \    /
              o--o
                  \
                   o   <-- br5
  ```

  There is no obvious thing to do for this particular case.  However, another variant *might* have a preferable review / pull-request ordering:

  ```
  ...--o--o   <-- origin/master
           \
            \      o   <-- br4
             \    /
              o--o
               \
                o   <-- br5
  ```

  (It would be more natural to draw this graph a bit differently; I drew it like this to make it easier to compare to the previous one.)  Here, if `br5` were accepted in its current form, `br4` would need two more commits to be approved to be accepted in *its* current form, and there are only two commits to review when doing `br5` first.  Should `br4` be reviewed first, there would be three commits to be reviewed, after which there would be only one to be reviewed.

  It's not clear *which* (if any) of these two is preferable, but at least there's some chance that the simple fact that the counts differ results in *a* preference.

With the above in mind, let's consider that earlier phrase, *see if some other* C<sub>j, j ≠ i</sub> *points to any of those commits.*

We can take this *literally* if we are not concerned with "bushy branches".  If neither of the last two graphs is allowed to occur at all, then either some other branch tip literally *is* one of the commits in `git rev-list origin/master..Bi`, and we should review via that other name first; or else *B<sub>i</sub>* is "stand-alone" for review purposes.

If "bushiness" may occur, no simple rule covers everything due to the cases outlined above.

There are several ways to test for some *B<sub>j</sub>* matching one of the commits produced by the above `git rev-list`, but the simplest and most straightforward is literally to see if `git rev-parse Bj` produces one of the hash IDs produced by the `git rev-list`.  If so, we should review the *B<sub>j</sub>* name first.  In fact, we should find the *B<sub>j</sub>* that's "closest to" the `origin/master` commit, which we can do by running a separate `git rev-list --count origin/master..Bj` on each such *B<sub>j</sub>*.  The one with the lowest count "wins", and all others are pushed off for later, just like *B<sub>i</sub>*.  By making sure that each *B<sub>i</sub>* points to a unique *C<sub>i</sub>* we ensure that there are no ties in this process.

Your `--simplify-by-decoration` trick is promising as well.  It has the same constraints as the straightforward graph technique I outline above (with the minor flaw that you cannot check for, and ensure, that the constraints are met using just `--simplify-by-decoration`).